# Routing on nested modules in Angular without children?

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, angular-module

I have 3 modules:

1. `AppModule` that is my root module,
2. `ModuleAModule`,
3. `ModuleBModule`.

Each module has own `routing.module.ts`.
I want to build routes like `ROOT/module-a/module-b`

I prepared 2 versions (with and without `children` property):

1. [Non-working version without children](https://stackblitz.com/edit/embedded-routes-without-children)
2. [Working version with children property](https://stackblitz.com/edit/embedded-routes-with-children)

These files have differences for both version:

- app/modules/module-a/module-a.routing.module.ts
- app/modules/module-b/module-b.routing.module.ts

**The issue**: I would like to store paths independently: without using the `children[]` property. If it is possible.
I don't use `children[]` in `AppRoutingModule` for `ModuleARoutingModule`. But why I can't do the same between `ModuleARoutingModule` and `ModuleBRoutingModule`?

#### Non-working snippets

`app.routing.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
        ModuleARoutingModule,
    ],
    exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
```

`module-a.routing.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'module-a', component: ModuleAComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
        ModuleBRoutingModule,
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

`module-b.routing.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'module-b', component: ModuleBComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

But I get

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL
>   Segment: 'module-a/module-b' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL
>   Segment: 'module-a/module-b'

#### Working snippets

To solve this issue:

- I added `children[]` property in `module-a.routing.ts` and removed
  `ModuleBRoutingModule` from imports.

`module-a.routing.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'module-a',
        component: ModuleAComponent,
        children: [
            // via loadChildren or component
            { path: 'module-b', loadChildren: '../module-b/module-b.module#ModuleBModule' },
        ]
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild(routes),
        // ModuleBRoutingModule,
    ],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

- Also I rewrote `module-b.routing.ts` (made `path=''` as empty).

`module-b.routing.ts`

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: ModuleBComponent }
];
```

### Question

Could I solve this issue without `children[]` property or do I always need to use `children`?

Comment: i don't think this is correct solution. Because you are including the 2 sub routings in main routing whch is not correct. This will work. But Ideally not a good solution. Here what we want is that without routing, can it be done? One way i am thinking, can we add bootstraping ModuleAComponent and ModuleBComponent respectively in every nested module?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

You only need the `children` property if you have multiple levels of router outlets.

Did you try this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ModuleARoutingModule } from './modules/module-a/module-a.routing.module';
import { ModuleBRoutingModule } from './modules/module-b/module-b.routing.module';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full', }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ModuleARoutingModule,
    ModuleBRoutingModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**UPDATE:**

I spent some time with your stackblitz code and you *do* need to use `children` because you *do* have nested router outlets. If you remove the nested router outlets, then you don't need to use `children`.

I have an updated and working version of your non-working code with no `children` here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/embedded-routes-without-children-kd1hms